# Why I'm getting reputation for this?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

[image]
One of my answer was removed by a mod but I got reputation for this! but Why?Is it abug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answer was downvoted twice, once on October 23rd, once today. Your net reputation has not changed as a result of that post.

Answer (score 1):

## There is no bug

You can never be sure with downvotes, even mods have somewhat limited information on this.  But to get +4 rep like that you would have to have a post with two downvotes (and no upvotes) deleted.  The system would give you back the 4 reputation taken by downvotes.  Moderators deleting a post carries no penalties other than the potential change in reputation.

You indeed do have a post that meets those criteria, so I would say that this is what happened.